# Openfiledialog method alternative in lotus script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Is it possible to get all files (ex : jpg images) from a particular folder with out using openfiledialog method in lotus script? In lotus script, we can give the file path as hard coded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Dir` to get all files from a folder:

```vb
Dim pathName As String
Dim fileName As String
pathName = "C:\yourFolder\"
fileName = Dir(pathName + "*.jpg", 0)
Do While fileName <> ""
    Print pathName + fileName
    fileName = Dir()
Loop
```

This sample code prints all your jpg files from yourFolder like

```vb
C:\yourFolder\a.jpg
C:\yourFolder\b.jpg
C:\yourFolder\c.jpg
```

From there you can use the list to attach the files to a document or whatever you want to do with the files.

[Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_DIR_FUNCTION.html&resultof=%22dir%22%20) you can find the description.

Comment: Knut Herrmann, openfiledialog method, we can get the file object(Image) but Dir method only return file names? Please help on this.

Comment: Use `EmbedObject` method of `NotesRichTextItem` class to attach or embed the files in a document: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_EMBEDOBJECT_METHOD.html&resultof=%22EmbedObject%22%20%22embedobject%22%20